# Centralizer of $M \otimes M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field, $V$ a finite-dimensional $k$-vectorspace and $M \in End(V)$. How can I determine $Z$, the centralizer of $M \otimes M$ in $End(V) \otimes End(V)$?

For example, if 
$$M=[[1,0],[0,2]],$$ then $M$ is 6-dimensional, consisting of block matrices of shape 1,2,1.

I was confused at first, because this seems to be a contradiction to the fact that the centralizer of a subalgebra of the form $A \otimes B$ is just the tensor product of the centralizers of $A$ and $B$; but here we are considering only the element $M \otimes M$, not $A \otimes A$, where $A$ is the subalgebra generated by $M$.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like it can get complicated. Generically, at least over an algebraically
closed field, a matrix $M$ will have distinct eigenvalues $m_1,\ldots,m_n$,
and generically $M\otimes M$ will have distinct eigenvalues $m_1^2,\ldots,m_n^2$
with multiplicity one, and $m_1m_2,m_1m_3,\ldots,m_{n-1}m_n$ with
multiplicity two. Thus the centralizer will have dimension $n+4{n\choose 2}=2n^2-n$.

But there are many degenerate cases: for instance if $M$ has eigenvalues
$1,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}$ then $M\otimes M$ will have eigenvalues
$1,a,\ldots,a^{2n-2}$ with multiplicities $1,2,\ldots n-1,n,n-1,\ldots,1$.
Things can get more complicated still.

Then $M$ might have non-trivial Jordan blocks, and then the real fun starts!

Comment: It's reasonably well understood (and in the literature in many places, eg in work by B. Srinivasan, circa 1956) how to caclulate the Jordan blocks of $M \otimes M$ from that of $M.$ The famous (at least among group theorists) Hall-Higman paper (PLMS,1956) computes the centralizer of an element a single eigenvalue $1$ but arbitrary Jordan normal form. This suffices to do the general case ( as Robin suggests, the answer is far from pretty).

Comment: The well know «famous among the people who know about it» paper :) Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @Mariano: Well, I specified the paper reasonably tightly, but it's in Mathscinet as MR0072872.

Comment: I was not complaining about that or anything, really :)

Comment: @Mariano: Sure, I know, but I thought I might as well put in a bit more about it.